# Rails 5 System Tests won't stay in background! (Capybara with Selenium and Chrome)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

When I run my massive suite of Capybara "system" tests, the automated Chrome window constantly takes focus! It basically means I can't work while the test is running. This is driving me insane. Is there anything I can do? It didn't do this until recently.

Gems:

- rails 5.2.0
- capybara 3.0.3
- selenium-webdriver 3.12.0
- chromedriver-helper 1.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't configured your selenium webdriver correctly. From my 5.2 app:

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb
require 'capybara/rspec'                                                                
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than running in headless mode (or filing an issue with the Chrome developers and hoping they change the behavior in a future version of Chrome) there is nothing you can do